# android RegEx external GPS string

Tags: android, regex, gps

I have a problem with seperating information in a string i get from the external GPS stream.

Heres a example of a string:

```
$GPGSV,3,3,12,22,09,276,31,25,24,247,24,27,54,131,,32,04,359,19*71
$GPGLL,5703.85365,N,00953.88360,E,075510.00,A,A*69
$GPPWR,028a,1,0,1,1
$GPRMC,075511.00,A,5703.85369,N,00953.88430,E,0.335,302.17,070912,,,A*6E
$GPVTG,302.17,T,,M,0.335,N,0.621,K,A*3A
```

Want i am trying to do is to get the " `$GPGLL,5703.85365,N,00953.88360,E,075510.00,A,A*69` " out so i can grab the longtitude and latitude and then update my textview with it. But keep getting string out of bounch exeption and i start wondering if i am handling this in the wrong way.

Anyone that can put me in the right direction in how to solve this?

Comment: Do you think it would help for you to provide the regex you're currently using, the snippet of code preceding the "out of bounds" exception, and maybe the stack trace?

Comment: I would suggest NOT using RegEx and simply parsing the string manually using $ and , as your points of reference. Should not be to difficult.

Comment: i did not think of that.. I will try and do it that way. Thank you Jug6ernaut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach to handling NMEA sentences directly from the GPS:

```
    // Listener for NMEA sentences
public void  onNmeaReceived(long timestamp, String nmea) {
            // Split the sentence into its comma-separated pieces
    String [] sentence = nmea.split(",");
            // See if it's the sentence we're interested in
    if(sentence[0].equalsIgnoreCase("$GPGLL")) {
    /* In here, process the data components of the sentence, which will
               be in sentence[1], sentence[2], etc. */
        }
    }
}
```